# Spinner: Storing and Retrieving value using Shared Preferences in Android

Tags: android

I cannot retrieve the selected value of the spinner. Can somebody help me? Thanks.

This is how I retrieve the data. It's inside the `onCreate()` method.

```
mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
SpinnerLang.setSelection(mPrefs.getInt(PREF_SPINNER, 0));
```

Then I save the Spinner's value in a button, so when the user selects from the Spinner and clicks the button the selected value will be saved.

```
//Listening to button event
btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Editor e = mPrefs.edit();
    int Spinnervalue = SpinnerLang.getSelectedItemPosition();
    e.putInt("PREF_SPINNER", Spinnervalue);
    e.commit();
  }
```

Comment: You must set the spinner selected item from preference after you have initiated the spinner (set the spinner adapter) ,  or it will default to the first item

Comment: see my updated answer for a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()` to store the selected item position in preference

```
    spinner.setAdapter(mySpinnerAdapter);   

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        /**
         * Called when a new item is selected (in the Spinner)
         */
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int position, long id) {
            mPrefs.edit().putInt("PREF_SPINNER", position).commit();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    }); // (optional)

    //UPDATE - When you are using a button onCLick()
    // to set the spinner selection:
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinner.setSelection(mPrefs.getInt("PREF_SPINNER", 0));

        }
    });



     // set the spinner selected item from preference after 
     // spinner.setAdapter(mySpinnerAdapter);
     // -or it will default to the first item
 //    spinner.setSelection(mPrefs.getInt(PREF_SPINNER, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have these methods that you can use depending on how you have declared your spinner.

[getSelectedItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29)

[getSelectedItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemId%28%29)

[getSelectedItemId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure constant PREF_SPINNER and "PREF_SPINNER" used has same value assigned to it in your code

```
mPrefs.getInt(PREF_SPINNER, 0)
e.putInt("PREF_SPINNER", Spinnervalue);
```